# How to show time on seekbar hover

Tags: javascript

At the present time, I am making my HTML5 Player with my own design and functionality.

It was decided to make a progress bar with the help of an element of  `<input type="range" />` 
The simplest example can be found [a here](https://codepen.io/pen/mYOzLQ).

During testing, the following problems appeared:

1. If you pause the video and click anywhere on the progress bar, the slider will move to the cursor with some kind of bounce in a big direction.
2. If you play around with the same progress bar, you will notice that if you hover the cursor, a block will appear with a preview of the frame and time, and if you press in the same place on the progress bar, it will switch to this of time.

The whole point is that these times are sometimes not the same. For example, you hover the cursor on the progress bar, you thought the time, for example, 00:10. And, if you don’t move the mouse and click right there, the video should go to 10 seconds (logically), but in fact, the video goes to 00:11. But this is not always the case, this is especially noticeable at the beginning of the video, and not immediately

All this is very well implemented in the [a Plyr](https://plyr.io/) player: that is, it was pointed at the progress bar, for example, at 00:55, clicked, the slider went to this position without bounce, the current time is clearly shown as 00:55, no more, no less. Everything is ok, everything is cool!

Do you have any problems in solving these problems and have you encountered similar problems? Or is it just me?
I will be glad to any answers and advice

Comment: Maybe you can check out Plyr's source code to learn how did they solve this problems?

Comment: Browsers quirky behavior could be unsatisfying sometimes, but it's almost always have some workaround. You have to debug your issue and take a look at every step of data flow n your program. Somewhere you will find a discrepancy with some particular code behavior and with a compact demonstration of an issue you can post here again and find a concrete solution. You formulated a very broad question this time.